# Yii rights table does not store data when user is registered

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions

I have do lot of try for the query is execute in user model. My data is insert in (user, authassignment, authitem, authitemchild) these table but does not insert in Rights table.

```
public function afterSave() {
    if ($this->isNewRecord) {
        $model = User::model()->findByPk($this->id);
        echo     $role = ucfirst($model->usertype); die;
        $authorizer = Yii::app()->getModule("rights")->getAuthorizer();
        $authorizer->authManager->assign($role, $this->id);
        return parent::afterSave();
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no need for `$model = User::model()->findByPk($this->id)` because `$model` = `$this`. You also have an unnecessary `die`.

Comment: Yaa i have remove die and User::model()->findByPk($this->id) ,But does not work yet

Comment: Have you set up `rights` as your `authManager` in your config file?